# Bash ftp backup and keep just some archives

Tags: string, bash, parsing, ftp

Good day. I have an important question. I need to know how can i delete the first file on ftp server. I have 5 backups on my ftp server which are called `date.filename.tar.bz2`. And I am making the sixth archive, but I need ftp-server keep only 5 last backups. I can do something like that

```
delfile=$(echo ls *.tar.bz2 | lftp $user:$pass@$host:/ | head -n1)
```

But I get a string: `-rw------- 1 1001 1001 0 dec 14 hr:min filenmae.tar.bz2`
And I can't delete file just typing `delete $delfile`
I need to parse the string and get just `filename.tar.bz2`.
Please help, how can this string can be parsed?
I post my script for a good understanding

```
#!/bin/bash           
HOST=10.10.x.x                 
USER=ftpuser                  
PASSWORD=ftpuserpass
TEMP="/tmp/backup"
if [ ! -d "$TEMP" ]; then
    mkdir $TEMP
fi
fname="$(basename -- $1)"
tar -cvjf $TEMP/$today.$fname.tar.bz2 $1
x=$(echo ls *.tar.bz2 | lftp $USER:$PASSWORD@$HOST:/ | wc -l)
if [ "$x" -ge 5 ]; then              
#here is a trouble
#i need to do something like that
#delfile=$(echo ls *.tar.bz2 | lftp $USER:$PASSWORD@$HOST:/ | head -n1)
#ftp -inv $HOST <<EOF            
#user $USER $PASSWORD                                   
#delete $delfile                     
#bye                                   
#EOF
#but delfile gets a string -rw------- 1 1001 1001 0 Dec 14 17:55 test.tar.bz2
#and i don't now how to make it get just test.tar.bz2
else
ftp -inv $HOST <<EOF            
user $USER $PASSWORD                 
lcd $TEMP                  
mput *.tar.bz2                       
bye                                   
EOF
cd $TEMP 
rm *.tar.bz2
fi
```

Comment: [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: What do you mean? Ok. I post my script, for a good underdtanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit this line:

```
delfile=$(echo ls *.tar.bz2 | lftp $USER:$PASSWORD@$HOST:/ | head -n1)
```

to be like this:

```
delfile=$(echo ls *.tar.bz2 | lftp $USER:$PASSWORD@$HOST:/ | head -n1|awk '{print $NF}')
```

And you will have on filename in the variable

Comment: It's seems to be OK. You're helped me very much. Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you are happy with my answer feel free to upvote and/or accept it :)

Comment: it's still 550 Remove directory operation failed. But doesn't metter. I'll be able to finish this script by myself. Thank you once again!

Comment: @OlegBelous, no problem :)